# How to download OSM 3D building data?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, json

I have OSM data (2D) data from Geofabrik now i need 3D building data for my study. I found one web server where i got OSM 3D buildings
https://osmbuildings.org. Now i need to either crawl this data and convert it into json file which i can use it in QGIS. Anyone having idea how i can get this kind of 3D building data which i can fetch it in QGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.osm.pbf` data from Geofabrik conatins **ALL** OSM data, including the 3D information to render the buildings.

You just need the suitable rendering software for it. https://osmbuildings.org/developer/ and http://osm2world.org/download/ are some of them.

The only thing that is not incorporated is elevation data of the Earth surface. You would need SRTM or similar if you want that rendered too.

Comment: Note that shapefiles from Geofabrik don't contain all data as far as I know. Planet dumps and extracts however do contain everything.

Comment: Your first link is now broken (HTTP error 500).

Comment: @Ruslan fixed for now.

Comment: Looking at the OSM data I don't see nearly enough "building:part" and "height" tags to render what's on https://osmbuildings.org. Are the 3D buildings encoded in some other way in the OSM data?

Comment: Most probably they take buildings with one building level unless explicitly stated in the tags.